# Add custom HTML attributes with no value to JSX

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

I have some HTML that needs custom attributes with no value dependent on the situation.. for example these are all valid:

```
<div className="playlist-row" selected>
<div className="playlist-row" active>   
<div className="playlist-row">
```

i tried doing something like

```
let customAttr = {'active'};  // incorrect syntax
let customAttr = {'active': true};  //doesn't work
let customAttr = {'active': ''};  //doesn't work

<div className="playlist-row" {...customAttr}>
```

Any ideas of how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should do it - in your `render()` function:

```
render() {
    let customAttr = "active"

    return (
        <div className={"playlist-row " + customAttr}>
    )
}
```

or alternately, you could avoid string concatenation...

```
<div className={`playlist-row ${customAttr}`}>
```

Comment: unfortunately didn't work, ty for trying though.  i think because active isn't part of the class name?  im just guessing..

Comment: @user1189352 Hmm... I've edited my response to make it a more fleshed-out render function - does yours basically look like this?  Defining `customAttr`, then returning the element?

Comment: oh snap it worked.  i just had a typo on my end.  thank you!

Comment: @user1189352 Great! Glad that helped. Don't forget to accept the answer - I think this is a common problem, will be helpful to the community.